# IntelliJ IDEA using JavaScript "version" of dependency specified in Gradle build file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

This issue just recently (past couple days) started occurring on one of my development machines.

I'm using Eclipse's Vert.x dependency for a web project:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    // Vert.x for web framework
    compile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-core', version: '3.4.2'
    compile group: 'io.vertx', name: 'vertx-web', version: '3.4.2'
    ...
}
```

This has worked fine in the past - I *think* the triggering action was my upgrading to IntelliJ 2017.2.2, but now:

1. IntelliJ cannot resolve any of the `-web` imports:

[image]

2. If I examine the Dependencies list for my Module, the **JavaScript** version of the dependency is shown?

**How did this happen**, and how can I make sure it's properly recognized as a Java dependency?

[image]

**Edit:** Sample project available here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177950

Comment: Just a hunch, try moving your Kotlin `apply plugin ...` lines to below the `dependencies`, and/or Kotlin `compile ...` lines to the end within the `dependencies`, and full gradle resync.

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, if I can reproduce in a smaller project I will be sure to do so.

Comment: @CrazyCoder issue opened, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-177950. I've also updated this question with the same project for anyone interested in toying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Kotlin plugin which is fixed in version 1.1.4-2. After you update the plugin, you need to delete the incorrect libraries and reimport your project from Gradle to have your project fixed.

Comment: Indeed it is! As the JetBrains issue tracker is not publicly indexable, nothing came up in my searches. (And I searched less thoroughly through the tracker myself.) For reference, it is this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-19717

Answer (score 0):

If you face such problems, the first two things you always can do is:

1. (in IntellJ) `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`
2. (in IntellJ's Gradle Bar) Press button for `Refresh all gradle dependencies`

If this doesn't help, please check if `./gradlew clean testClasses` succeeds or also fails with such an error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all both, to no avail. The CLI build is fine - the dependency resolution seems to be isolated to IntelliJ.

Comment: Hm, that's really interesting. Just tried that out also with IntelliJ 2017.2.2 -> works perfectly fine. Can you provide your whole gradle file?